# Ignoring ActionFilterAttribute, although explicitly defined on controller / action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, attributes

I've got an ASP.NET middleware in the form of `ActionFilterAttribute`.

For example:

```
[CacheResponse(Seconds = 3)]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Echo(string userId, string message, string queryString)
{
    await Task.Delay(150);
    return Ok(new {Action = "Echo", UserId = userId, Message = message, QueryString = queryString});
}
```

The attribute `CacheResponse` is a nuget, I cannot touch its code.
Yet I would like to have a feature-on/off configuration, so if I want to disable the cache mechanism, I won't have to do changes in the code.

How could I "cancel" the subscription of some controllers / actions to attributes? even though it's explicitly decorated with it?

I'm looking for a piece of code to run on webrole startup, that given the configuration value for the feature-on/off would cancell the decoration.

Thank you

Comment: How do you register the middleware in the Startup.cs?

Comment: I do not register anything in the `Startup.cs`. I just put an attribute on the Controller / Action and it happens magically :)

Comment: You may wrap the Attribute with your custom attribute, where you decide whether you use it or not. But I'm no expert with filter attributes.

Comment: Can you show an example? i'm not sure what you're suggesting..

Comment: You can create your own actionfilterattribute and override OnActionExecuting() There you can put the Code whether you call OnActionExecuting() from the Chache attribute. This is the tutorial: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd410056(v=vs.98).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented Nikolaus's idea. Code might look like:

```
public class ConfigurableCacheResponseAttribute : CacheResponseAttribute
{
    //Property injection
    public IApplicationConfig ApplicationConfig { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        if (this.ApplicationConfig.Get<bool>("CashingEnabled"))
        {
            base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (this.ApplicationConfig.Get<bool>("CashingEnabled"))
        {
            return base.OnActionExecutedAsync(actionExecutedContext, cancellationToken);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (this.ApplicationConfig.Get<bool>("CashingEnabled"))
        {
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }

    public override Task OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (this.ApplicationConfig.Get<bool>("CashingEnabled"))
        {
            return base.OnActionExecutingAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
        }

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

How to use dependency injection with filter attribute you could find [here](https://michael-mckenna.com/dependency-injection-for-asp-net-web-api-action-filters-in-3-easy-steps/).